# Get latest payment from related model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

I'd like to output a table using "Premises" model in Django admin. In addition I'd like include the output in this table of an additional column, say "last utility payment". It is actually a column in a related table. There may be no payment in the database so admin should able to see either an empty cell or the date of payment.

I was able to write a DB query that displays the information I need. Its significant and worked part is given below:

```
SELECT jp.id,
       jp.number apartment,
       jp.building_number building,
       jp.rent,
       jp.arrears,
       jpm.last_payment
FROM jasmin_premises jp
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT pm.premises_id,
               max(pm.paid) last_payment
        FROM jasmin_payment pm
        GROUP BY pm.premises_id
    ) jpm ON jp.id = jpm.premises_id;
```

And the output is similar to the following:

```
id  | apartment | building | rent   | arrears | last_payment
--------------------------------------------------------------
170 | 1X        | 6-A      | 297.43 | 2.57,   | NULL
72  | 2         | 4        | 289.66 | -678.38 | 2021-01-31
173 | 3Z        | 7        | 432.86 | 515.72  | 2021-02-04
73  | 4         | 8-B      | 292.25 | 515.44  | 2021-02-04
74  | 5         | 8-B      | 112.42 | 3249.34 | NULL
75  | 6A        | 122      | 328.48 | 386.23  | 2021-02-04
76  | 7         | 42       | 482.06 | 964.12  | 2021-01-31
77  | 8         | 1        | 433.71 | 867.42  | 2021-01-31
78  | 9C        | 12       | 322.79 | 322.79  | 2021-02-04
79  | 10        | 122      | 324.22 | 0       | 2021-02-04
80  | 12        | 12       | 322.79 | 1232.46 | NULL
81  | 14        | 5-Z      | 440.82 | 978.44  | 2021-02-04
```

And  I'm using the following models (only a significant part):

```
class Premises(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_length=10)

    building_number = models.CharField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_length=3)

    rent = models.DecimalField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_digits=12,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.0)

    area = models.DecimalField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        max_digits=5,
        decimal_places=2)

class Payment(models.Model):
    paid = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False)

    premises = models.ForeignKey(
        Premises,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='payments',
        db_index=True)
```

Is there a way to override `admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset` (for example using annotations) to get an extra column like in my example above? Is there any other way to make a LEFT JOIN on a compound DB query using Django ORM?

Comment: Hello sir, i don't know if displaying this in django admin is the best way because it gets more complicated, in my opinion you should create a html template to display this informations, if you chose this last option, i will be able to help you.

Comment: @Luiz The problem is to make a single DB query using Django ORM. Whether it will be the admin site or some other place is not so important in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add an explicit subquery to a **QuerySet** using the **Subquery** expression. We'll need also to use **OuterRef** because a queryset in a **Subquery** needs to refer to a field from the outer query.

So let's create a subquery:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef

payments = Payment.objects.filter(
    premises=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-paid')
```

The next step is to pass `payments` subquery to a queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

# 'payments' here is from example above
premises = Premises.objects.annotate(
    last_payment=Subquery(payments.values('paid')[:1])
)
```

Finally, lets see the used SQL to query objects rows the database:

```
print(premises.query)
```

(the output is formatted, only the significant part is shown)

```
SELECT "jasmin_premises"."id",
       "jasmin_premises"."number",
       "jasmin_premises"."building_number",
       "jasmin_premises"."arrears",
       "jasmin_premises"."rent",
       (SELECT U0."paid"
        FROM "jasmin_payment" U0
        WHERE U0."premises_id" = "jasmin_premises"."id"
        ORDER BY U0."paid" DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS "last_payment"
FROM "jasmin_premises";
```

Now, after performing the tests, we can use this in our ModelAdmin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

from .models import Payment, Premises


@admin.register(Premises)
class PremisesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'number',
        'building_number',
        'rent',
        'arrears',
        'last_payment',
    )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)

        payments = Payment.objects.filter(
            premises=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-paid')

        qs = qs.annotate(
            last_payment=Subquery(payments.values('paid')[:1]),
        )

        return qs

    def last_payment(self, obj):
        return obj.last_payment
    last_payment.short_description = 'Last payment'
    last_payment.admin_order_field = 'last_payment'
```

Well, this doesn't use JOINs, but this approach will force Django to execute a subquery.

Probably in some cases it may be possible to write an equivalent queryset that performs the same task more clearly or efficiently however, this is the best I have achieved so far.

Answer (score 0):

to make this query in django you have to add the models.Manager() to the tables like this:

#### models.py

```
class Premises(models.Model):
    # existent code
    objects = models.Manager()


class Payment(models.Model):
    # existent code
    objects = models.Manager()
```

In the part of app you want to access this information

```
from .models import Premises, Payment

premises = Premises.objects.all()
data_to_display = []
for premise in premises:
    payments = Payment.objects.filter(premises=premise).order_by('-paid')
    if len(payments) == 0:
        last_payment = "Null"
    else:
        last_payment = payments[0]
    object_to_list = {
        "id": premise.id,
        "apartment": premise.number,
        "building": premise.building_number,
        "rent": premise.rent,
        "arreaars": premise.area,
        "last_payment": last_payment.paid
    }
    data_to_display.append(object_to_list)
```

Comment: This is actually no a bad approach. However, what doesn't suit me is that this code will make as many queries to the database as you have records in the table. But I'd like make a single DB query to get all records with an additional column from a related table

Comment: @serghei So i think the only way is to make raw querys https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/ it's very good tool